# Numpyic way to sort an ndarray clockwise?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I am trying to sort a numpy ndarray clockwise (in ascending order). You can understand it as taking all the values in the array, sort them, then lay them out in a clockwise spiral to a new array with the same shape. The directions of the clockwise spiral are shown below:

[image]

For example, say I have an array of

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array(([2, 4, 6],
               [1, 5, 3],
               [7, 9, 8]))
```

The expected output is

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [8, 9, 4],
          [7, 6, 5]])
```

If I have an array of

```
a2 = np.array(([2, 4, 6],
               [1, 5, 3],
               [7, 9, 8],
               [12, 11, 10]))
```

The expected output is

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [10, 11, 4],
          [9, 12, 5],
          [8, 7, 6]])
```

### What I have tried so far

My idea is to track the row index `x` and the column index `y` of the moving iterator and the current index `cur` of the sorted flattened list `sa`. The number of rows to go through (`lenr`) and the number of columns to go through (`lenc`) are subtracted by `1` once the moving iterator passes `lenr` rows horizontally and `lenc` columns vertically. Here is the function that I managed to write:

```
def clockwise_sorted(a, key=None, reverse=False):
    nr, nc = a.shape
    res = a.tolist()
    sa = a.ravel().tolist()
    if key is None:
        sa.sort(reverse=reverse)
    else:
        sa.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)
    res[0] = sa[:nc]
    cur, lenr, lenc = nc, nr - 1, nc - 1
    x, y = 0, nc - 1
    while (lenc > 0 and lenr > 0):
        # go down, then go left
        for _ in range(lenr):
            x += 1
            res[x][y] = sa[cur]
            cur += 1
        for _ in range(lenc):
            y -= 1
            res[x][y] = sa[cur]
            cur += 1      
        lenr -= 1
        lenc -= 1
        
        # go up, then go right
        for _ in range(lenr):
            x -= 1
            res[x][y] = sa[cur]
            cur += 1
        for _ in range(lenc):
            y += 1 
            res[x][y] = sa[cur]
            cur += 1
        lenr -= 1
        lenc -= 1
    return np.array(res)
```

For square matrices, my code works fine:

```
print(clockwise_sorted(a1))
#[[1 2 3]
# [8 9 4]
# [7 6 5]]
#%timeit 5.98 µs ± 413 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But it doesn't work for non-square matrices:

```
print(clockwise_sorted(a2))
#[[ 1  2  3]
# [10 11  4]
# [ 9  9  5]
# [ 8  7  6]]
```

Clearly, it misses the `12` at `[2,1]`.

Please note that I don't expect you to understand and fix my code. I don't like my code so much because I feel like there should be more numpyic ways to do this. Therefore, I want to see some numpyic solutions. However, it would be nice if someone can comment on what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Clearly I'm missing something that everyone else is seeing, but I do not understand the procedure for converting the given inputs into the given outputs is supposed to work. E.g. how does the input `([2, 4, 6], [1, 5, 3], [7, 9, 8])` get turned into the output `[[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 4], [7, 6, 5]]` if not by some kind of arbitrary permutation? Based on the diagram I would have expected `[2, 4, 6, 3, 8, 9, 7, 1, 5]`. Would you consider editing the question to be a bit more clear about it?

Comment: @DavidZ Clearly you are missing the word "sort". I am trying to sort the array clockwise, not getting the sequence clockwise. If you read the expected output from 1 to 9, you will understand.

Comment: No, you're wrong. I'm not missing the word "sort". What do you mean by "sort the array clockwise", if not traversing it along the spiral indicated in your diagram?

Comment: @DavidZ OP means "take all the values in the array, sort them, then lay them out in a spiral".

Comment: @AKX Ahh, now I get it, thanks. That's much more clear; the expression "sort an array clockwise" makes no sense to me. I hope the question can be edited to clear that up (or I could make an edit myself but I don't want to infringe on Shaun's authorial discretion).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `numpy.rot90` with recursion to rotate clockwise over the array. Sort the values of the array after changing to 1d and edit the values in the array by it

```
def rotate(matrix, arr):
    if not len(matrix):
        return
    matrix[0] = arr[:len(matrix[0])]
    rotate(np.rot90(matrix[1:]), arr[len(matrix[0]):])

a1 = np.array(([2, 4, 6],
                [1, 5, 3],
                [7, 9, 8]))

sorted_arr = sorted(a1.ravel())
rotate(a1, sorted_arr)
print(a1)
```

Output

```
[[1 2 3]
 [8 9 4]
 [7 6 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is likely *hardly* the numpyiest solution, but I think it's a neat Pythonic solution, being a generator function that yields spiral coordinates in clockwise order that's then used to index the numpy array (which has to be transposed twice to get the coordinates right, but that's peanuts...).

```
import numpy as np


def spiral_coords(w, h):
    maxx = w - 1
    maxy = h - 1
    minx = miny = 0

    while (minx, miny) != (maxx, maxy):
        for x in range(minx, maxx):  # right
            yield (x, miny)
        yield (maxx, miny)  # upper-right corner
        for y in range(miny + 1, maxy):  # down
            yield (maxx, y)
        yield (maxx, maxy)  # lower-right corner
        for x in range(maxx - 1, minx, -1):  # left
            yield (x, maxy)
        yield (minx, maxy)  # lower-left corner
        for y in range(maxy - 1, miny, -1):  # up
            yield (minx, y)
        minx += 1
        miny += 1
        maxx -= 1
        maxy -= 1
    yield (minx, miny)  # final point


def clockwise_sorted(a):
    a = a.T
    nr, nc = a.shape
    sa = a.ravel()
    sa.sort()
    res = np.zeros_like(a)
    for (x, y), v in zip(spiral_coords(nr, nc), sa):
        res[x, y] = v
    return res.T


a2 = np.array(
    [
        [2, 4, 6],
        [1, 5, 3],
        [7, 9, 8],
        [12, 11, 10],
    ]
)

print(a2)
print(clockwise_sorted(a2))
```

This outputs

```
[[ 2  4  6]
 [ 1  5  3]
 [ 7  9  8]
 [12 11 10]]
[[ 1  2  3]
 [10 11  4]
 [ 9 12  5]
 [ 8  7  6]]
```

If you don't necessarily need Numpy, you can also use the same generator to spiralize anything into e.g. a mapping of coordinates to letters:

```
coords = {(x, y): c for (x, y), c in zip(spiral_coords(6, 5), "Hello World! This is a spiral!")}

for y in range(5):
    print("".join(coords.get((x, y), " ") for x in range(6)))
```

outputs

```
Hello 
 is aW
sal! o
iripsr
hT !dl
```